# Setar valor em campo de formulário (ou input de string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Tenho um campo de formulário que contém um JavaScript embutido, que funciona de maneira dinâmica.

```html
<input type="text" id="txtPreferencia" title="Tecla de atalho: Alt+R" name="txtPreferencia" class="infraText infraAutoCompletar" maxlength="300" tabindex="501" value="" autocomplete="off">
```

Esse campo lista valores, e eu preciso ou digitar nele um determinado valor, ou selecionar um dos valores suspensos da lista. Eu consigo localizar o elemento web:

```py
menu = browser.find_elements_by_id("txtPreferencia")
```

Mas não consigo digitar nada usando o comando `SEND_KEYS`, pois o programa dá erro quando tento. O erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#67>", line 1, in <module>
    menu.send_keys("Teste")
  File "C:\Users\Bergo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 349, in send_keys
    'value': keys_to_typing(value)})
  File "C:\Users\Bergo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\Bergo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Bergo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.142)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Comment: Cara, tenho quase certeza que é pelo  `find_elements_by_id` troca por `find_element_by_id`. Esse `find_elements_by_id` só é usado para buscar elementos que tem o mesmo `id` e ele te retorna um array. Se não for isso coloca erro que ta dando, ajuda a te ajudar!

Comment: Opa! Grato! Troquei, mas ele dá o mesmo erro quando tento executar um "SEND_KEYS".

Comment: coloca mais parte do teu código, como os `import`, por favor! so essa linha de código fica muito vago.

Comment: Olá. Agradeço o auxílio. Descobri que era meramente um "defeito" no driver do Chrome. Com a atualização, o funcionamento foi normalizado e o campo está interagindo com a aplicação normalmente!